# Can grid.arrange be used with objects different from ggplot class in R?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, gridextra

I have this problem. I need to put 4 graphs generated with the `ggplot2` package when using `grid.arrange`. So I construct my four plots with this code:

```
#type1
plot1<-ggplot(a,aes(x=sa$x,y=sa$values,color=sa$ind)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=sa$ind),alpha=0.4) +
  stat_summary(fun.y='mean',geom='line',colour="black",size=2) +
  labs(title="Gene expression profile",x="Developmental stage",y="log10(cpm)")

#type2
plot2<-ggplot(a,aes(x=factor(sa$x),y=sa$values,color=sa$ind))+
  stat_summary(fun.y='mean',geom='line',colour="black",aes(group=1),size=1)+
  labs(title="Gene expression profile",x="Developmental stage",y="log10(cpm)")+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5"),labels=c("SB","CB","G","GBE","DC"))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=sa$x),alpha=0.3,size=0.2,width=0.3,fill="pink")

#type3
plot3<-ggplot(a,aes(x=factor(sa$x),y=sa$values,color=sa$ind))+
  geom_line(aes(group=sa$ind),alpha=0.4)+
  stat_summary(fun.y='mean',geom='line',colour="black",aes(group=1),size=2)+
  labs(title="Gene expression profile",x="Developmental stage",y="log10(cpm)")+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5"),labels=c("SB","CB","G","GBE","DC"))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=sa$x),alpha=0.1,size=0.2,width=0.3)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(sa$x)),size=1)

#type4
plot4<-ggplot(a,aes(x=factor(sa$x),y=sa$values,color=sa$ind))+
  geom_smooth(aes(group=sa$x),method="auto")+
  labs(title="Gene expression profile",x="Developmental stage",y="log10(cpm)")+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5"),labels=c("SB","CB","G","GBE","DC"))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=sa$x),alpha=0.1,size=0.2,width=0.3)+
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(sa$x)),size=1)

grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4,ncol=2,nrow=2,top="Graphics out panel")
```

After run this, I get the following error:

> Error in gList(S4 object of class c("gTableChild", "GGbio"), S4 object of class c("gTableChild",  :
>         only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
>       Además: Warning messages:
>       1: In class(grob) <- c("gTableChild", class(grob)) :
>         Configuración de clase (x) a varias cadenas ("gTableChild ", "GGbio ", ...); resultado ya no será un objeto S4
>       2: In class(grob) <- c("gTableChild", class(grob)) :
>         Configuración de clase (x) a varias cadenas ("gTableChild ", "GGbio ", ...); resultado ya no será un objeto S4
>       3: In class(grob) <- c("gTableChild", class(grob)) :
>         Configuración de clase (x) a varias cadenas ("gTableChild ", "GGbio ", ...); resultado ya no será un objeto S4
>       4: In class(grob) <- c("gTableChild", class(grob)) :
>         Configuración de clase (x) a varias cadenas ("gTableChild ", "GGbio ", ...); resultado ya no será un objeto S4

So,I try with a basic example for `grid.arrange`, and works like a charm:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(200),v2 = rnorm(200),v3 = rnorm(200),v4 = rnorm(200))
p1 <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x=v1))
p2 <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x=v2))
p3 <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x=v3))
p4 <- ggplot(df) + geom_density(aes(x=v4))
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,ncol=2,nrow=2,top="test")
```

So, I compare the class of p1 and my plot1 and note this:

```
> class(p1)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
> class(plot1)
[1] "GGbio"
attr(,"package")
[1] "ggbio"
```

Does anybody have an idea if my plots can be ordered using `grid.arrange` or maybe another library... (of course this can be done with Photoshop, but the idea is put the graph generation in a more complex pipeline).

Comment: not sure if this is the problem, but it is rarely a good ides to use `$` inside `aes ` as in plot1 to 4 (also you use `sa$`, but your data is `a`)

Comment: Damm....your totally wrigth. I dont look the typo mistake in the data and when correct the "a" for "sa" all works fine!

Comment: `$` inside `aes` is _never_ a good idea

Comment: to answer the generic question, yes, `grid.arrange` can deal with generic grobs, lattice plots, or ggplot plots.